# How to achieve a water drop effect in css?

Tags: css, css-shapes

I have the following design in my website. How can this invert round corners effect can be achieved?

I am sure there are couple of ways. I am looking for the simplest most elegant way to do this.

I would love if you can share a plankr in the answer.

[image: Css round corners]

Comment: is the lower section a solid colour?

Comment: How is that an "inverted" rounded corner? It's just a regular rounded corner.

Comment: StackOverflow is a site for specific programming *problems*, not specific programming *requests*. You need to show code of your own attempt; otherwise this is a consulting project.

Comment: @TylerH : sometimes people don't have a clue and ask for inspiration, i.e. a few inputs. I do it myself, and I generously give back.

Comment: @TylerH: the question *would* be worth keeping, so long as OP provides *some basic* markup of attempts.

Comment: @gd1 That's good of you, but it's not what this site is for. Go to Codrops for inspiration :-)

Comment: *I would love if you can share a plankr in the answer* - This suggests that no attempt has been made... So this question is still off-topic, until the OP provides an initial attempt

Comment: While you'de fiddling, make clear whether you mean [risen](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/risen#English) (it rises all by itself) or [raised](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/raised#English) (it has been raised by something/one else)

Comment: I am really sorry for been in the wrong with policy but I do have no clue on how to do this, I really looking for an expert

Comment: @jbutler483 Yes both are solid, even if the image might look like it's gradient

Comment: @DavidMZ: I can only help you so much. You **have to** attempt a solution. It's not too late to include your attempts (it might even be worth reopening if you expand on the question!)

Answer (score 9):

A simple (yet possibly flawed, since i'm currently using set values) solution would be to use pseudo effects for this:

You can hover the snippet to see how it was constructed, too:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.upper {
  height: 300px;
  width: 540px;
  background: gray;
  position: relative;
}
.circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: tomato;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  line-height:100px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -70px;
  left: 200px;
  border: 20px solid white;
  text-align:center;
  transition:all 0.8s;
}
.circle:hover{
  border: 20px solid tomato;
  background:lightgray;
  }
.upper:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 0 0 25px 0;
  background: gray;
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  bottom: -25px;
  transition:all 0.8s;
}
.upper:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 25px;
  background: gray;
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  bottom: -25px;
  transition:all 0.8s;
  right: 0;
}
.upper:hover:before,.upper:hover:after{
  background:tomato;
  }
```

```html
<div class="upper">
  <div class="circle">Hover Bits</div>
</div>
```

---

Which goes by the assumption that you're lower section will be white/ a solid colour.

---

It is basically:

```
+---------------------------------+
|                                 |
|                                 |
|                                 |
|               ____              |
|              /    \             |
+-------------| text |------------+
               \____/  <-- has really thick border

+---------------------------------+
|                                 |
|                                 |
|                                 |
|____________   ____    __________|
|            \ /    \  /          |
+------------|| text ||-----------+
|____________/ \____/  \__________| <-- pseudo element
```

which would leave:

```
+---------------------------------+
|                                 |
|                                 |
|                                 |
|               ____              |
|              /    \             |
+             | text |            +
|____________/ \____/  \__________|
```